# use bootstrap filter in laravel pagination

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-blade

I am using bootstrap filter in my data table in laravel for searching data. As I am using laravel pagination in I have 30+ pages. But the filter only searching data from the current page. But I want to search data from the full data table ( all the 30 pages)

blade:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" class="form-control">

<table class="table table-sm text-sm table-hover">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                    
                    <th>Start Date</th>
                    <th>End Date</th>
                    <th>No Of Days</th>
                    
                </tr>
              </thead>

              <tbody>
              @foreach($leaves_list  as $key => $data)
                <tr>
                   
                    
                     <td>
                        {{$data->leave_start_date}}
                    </td>
                     <td>
                        {{$data->leave_end_date}}
                    </td>
                     <td>
                        {{$data->number_of_days_off}}
                    </td>
                   </tr>
                 </tbody>
                 </table>
```

script:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
     var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
     $(".table tr").filter(function() {
     $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
       });
      });
     });
```

controller:

```
        $leaves_list = DB::table('employee_leave')
                    ->orderBy('employee_leave_id', 'desc')
                    ->paginate(100);
                    
                    
        return view("leaves.index",compact('leaves_list'));
```

So I want to the search result of all the pages of pagination

Comment: You cannot filter all pages in that way. You need to use ajax or other js libraries or you need to send get request to server.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never, huh?
I believe you are around to mid level today, but I hope I can help some other folks on here.

The [Laravel Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests) return a object than contains a key called "next_page_url".
To check this info, if you dd(); the response, that is what you'll receive:

```
    {#294 ▼ // app\Http\Controllers\FooController.php:22
        +"current_page": 1
        +"data": array:7 [▶]
        +"last_page": 3
        [...]
        +"next_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/list?page=2"
        [...]
    }
```

Is on **next_page_url** that you gonna have the remaining objects of your requests.

Now, if you need all the objects non-paginated, I suggest you to **create another Request**, without using paginate methods, but the Where clauses to filtering, in this case.

```
DB::table('employee_leave')
    ->orderBy('employee_leave_id', 'desc')
    ->where('foo', '<>', 'bar');
```

Don't miss to use this requests only when necessary, avoiding too many requests on the database.

Best regards,
Bruno.